# dart FFI - Pointer to a Pointer

Tags: flutter, pointers, dart, ffi

In dart using the ffi library we can create a Pointer object two ways

```
Pointer<NativeType> foo = allocate();
Pointer<NativeType> bar = Pointer.fromAddress(int address);
```

We can also get the Pointer objects address using `int address = foo.address();`

If we want to create a Pointer from another Pointer object doing `final bar = Pointer.fromAddress(foo.address);`

Will the resulting type of `bar` be `Pointer<Pointer<Double>>` or will `bar` just be a copy of foo where `foo.address == bar.address`

If it simply clones the Pointer, how can we create a Pointer to another Pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
    Pointer ptrToCopy; // i will assume that you have this already...
    Pointer<Pointer<NativeType>> _ptrToPtr = allocate();
    _ptrToPtr.value = Pointer.fromAddress(ptrToCopy.adress);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? as far as I can tell that doesn't work or make sense. if `allocate()` return a Pointer<NativeType> in the original question, you can't assign that to Pointer<Pointer<NativeType>>

Comment: check again, i added more

Comment: thank you! that makes much more sense now. The piece I was missing was that you need to set the `value` property of an allocated pointer to the address using `Poiter.fromAddress()` instead of just using the `address` property of the original pointer directly.

Comment: I could not make this code create a working pointer to pointer. What worked was the code from the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70001800/841390