# Dart/Flutter FFI(Foreign Function Interface): calling a native function with output parameter using FFI in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi

How to call a native function with output parameter with Dart ffi, since dart doesn't support output parameters. i am looking for an alternative for something like this C# Code

```c#
[DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

String PrinterName="Printer1";
IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
OpenPrinter(PrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero)
```

Comment: Dart functions do not support out parameters. Because your function only has one out paramter, you could rewrite it to just return that pointer, if you have access to the native code...

Comment: thanks for replay. unfortunately i don't have access to native code (it is a windows driver file). is there any other workarounds to call such functions using ffi?

Comment: Well, you will probably have to write a wrapper library (probably in C++), that will export a C function that will then call the driver library and then return the pointer. But it feels like an ugly solution and there might be better options...

Answer (score 4):

```dart
// Allocate some memory for the output to be written to.
final Pointer<Pointer<duckdb_database>> outDb = calloc<Pointer<duckdb_database>>();
// That memory contains a null pointer (we used calloc to zero the memory).
assert(outDb.value == nullptr);

// The native function should populate that memory.
db.open_ext(outDb);
assert(outDb.value != nullptr);

// Our native API probably wants a `duckdb_database*` in the rest of the API, so lets keep that variable.
final Pointer<duckdb_database> db = outDb.value;
// Don't forget to free the memory that we had for the out parameter.
calloc.free(outDb);

// Use `db`...
```

The [SQLite sample](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/bda70c84892923769c40a131886d6e70fadc99cb/samples/ffi/sqlite/lib/src/database.dart#L27-L47) in the Dart SDK repo has the same pattern with out parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it by using `malloc` with zero length from `package:ffi`

```dart
final dbPointer = malloc.allocate<duckdb_database>(0);
print(dbPointer.value); // some initial value
db.open_ext(dbPointer);
print(dbPointer.value); // new value!!
```

Zero clue if this is "right", but it's working for me!

Comment: This is inefficient. You are probably allocating something like 4k or whatever the minimum is.