# MySqlX (C connector) with Dart's ffi brings error "NoSuchMethodError: The method 'FfiTrampoline' was called on null."

Tags: mysql, dart, ffi, connector

I am trying to directly connect to MYSQL with Dart using Dart's ffi package and the native C-Connector of MYSQL.

My Dart code is:

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

typedef CFun = Pointer Function(Pointer<Utf8>, Int32, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Pointer>?);
typedef DartFun = Pointer Function(Pointer<Utf8>, int, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Pointer>?);

void main() {
  final lib = DynamicLibrary.open('/usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn8.so.2');
  final fc = lib.lookup<NativeFunction<CFun>>('mysqlx_get_session');
  print('We have C: $fc');
  final DartFun fd = fc.asFunction();
  print('We have Dart: $fd');
  Pointer<Pointer>? error;
  Pointer? session;
  session = fd('localhost'.toNativeUtf8(), 33060, '*user*'.toNativeUtf8(), '*password*'.toNativeUtf8(), ''.toNativeUtf8(), error);
}
```

When running this I get this output:

```
We have Pointer<NativeFunction<(Pointer<Utf8>, Int32, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Pointer<NativeType>>?) => Pointer<NativeType>>>: address=0x7f5b9c78f770
We have Closure: (Pointer<Utf8>, int, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Pointer<NativeType>>?) => Pointer<NativeType>
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'FfiTrampoline' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: FfiTrampoline()
#0      FfiTrampoline (dart:ffi)
#1      main (package:greudb/src/connection.dart:37:14)
#2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

Trying the same in C it works perfectly:

```
#include <mysql-cppconn/mysqlx/xapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    mysqlx_session_t *session = 0;
    mysqlx_error_t *error = 0;
    session = mysqlx_get_session("localhost", 33060, "*user*", "*password*", "", &error);
    if(error != 0) {
        printf("%s/n", mysqlx_error_message(error));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I guess my Dart Function signatures are not correct, but no matter what I try it does not help.
MySQL's C documentation is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/group__xapi__sess.html

I am using Linux Fedora 33, MySQL community server 8, MySQL Connector C/C++ 8, Dart 202.8488.

Comment: My feeling is that the issue is translating the final argument (`mysqlx_error_t **error`) correctly. If you run it with `nullptr` instead, it looks like it completes. I'm not sure how to deal with that, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of looking around, [it appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722769/dart-ffi-pointer-to-a-pointer) you can create the appropriate type for `error` using:

```
final error = calloc<Pointer>();
```

which under the hood calls `calloc.allocate<Pointer>(...)` with the appropriate `byteCount`. As this is unmanaged memory, you'll need to remember to release it by calling:

```
calloc.free(error);
```

once you're done with it.

Thankfully, the `mysqlx` API seems to treat all the structs as opaque, so you can determine what the actual error was by doing something like the following:

```
final message = errorMessage(error.value);
print(message.toDartString());
```

On the topic of releasing memory, the `Pointer<Utf8>` values created by calling `toNativeUtf8()` also need to be freed.

Putting all that together:

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

typedef _GetSession = Pointer Function(Pointer<Utf8>, Int32, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Pointer>);
typedef GetSession = Pointer Function(Pointer<Utf8>, int, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Utf8>, Pointer<Pointer>);

typedef _CloseSession = Void Function(Pointer);
typedef CloseSession = void Function(Pointer);

typedef _ErrorMessage = Pointer<Utf8> Function(Pointer);
typedef ErrorMessage = Pointer<Utf8> Function(Pointer);

void main() {
  final lib = DynamicLibrary.open('/usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn8.so.2');
  final GetSession getSession = lib.lookup<NativeFunction<_GetSession>>('mysqlx_get_session').asFunction();
  final CloseSession closeSession = lib.lookup<NativeFunction<_CloseSession>>('mysqlx_session_close').asFunction();
  final ErrorMessage errorMessage = lib.lookup<NativeFunction<_ErrorMessage>>('mysqlx_error_message').asFunction();

  final host = 'localhost'.toNativeUtf8();
  final user = 'user'.toNativeUtf8();
  final password = 'password'.toNativeUtf8();
  final database = ''.toNativeUtf8();
  final error = calloc<Pointer>();

  final session = getSession(host, 33060, user, password, database, error);

  calloc.free(host);
  calloc.free(user);
  calloc.free(password);
  calloc.free(database);

  if (error.value != nullptr) {
    final message = errorMessage(error.value);
    print(message.toDartString());

    calloc.free(error);
    return;
  }

  // Do something with session

  closeSession(session);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot. It works perfectly when I use the correct login credentials, if I pass something wrong (like a wrong user name) I get a segmentation fault. I have to dig deeper into this, yet this was most helpful.

Comment: Every time when the library throws a C++ exception class I get the segmentation fault. I am not sure if this is a problem of ffi, since using the connector libraries has some limitations (like rather building it from source instead of using the binary packages. Yet if I build a small C/C++ dynamic library as a wrapper and link the static connector libraries into it the throwing of exceptions works as expected. So at least I can do that as a workaround.

Comment: Ah yes, C++ exceptions. I think you will have to wrap it, as you've described, and catch any exceptions raised from the library itself. Definitely one of the annoyances of using FFI, if it's any more complicated than C, it becomes tricky.